# Okhttp Authenticator addHeader() vs header()

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp, restful-authentication

While using an Interceptor and Authenticator to add an access token header, my Authenticator correctly gets called when the server responds with a 401.

The Authenticator renews the access token via a separate network call and sets it in the header to try again. The code would be very similar [to this sample](https://www.coderdump.net/2018/04/automatic-refresh-api-token-with-retrofit-and-okhttp-authenticator.html)

I just spent an hour figuring out I used the wrong method to add the renewed token to the authenticator, [`addHeader` vs `header`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Request.Builder.html).

Works:

```
if (accessToken != null){
   // retry the failed 401 request with new access token
   return response.request().newBuilder()
                            .header("Authorization", accessToken) // use the new access token
                            .build();
}
```

Doesn't work:

```
if (accessToken != null){
   // retry the failed 401 request with new access token
   return response.request().newBuilder()
                            .addHeader("Authorization", accessToken) // use the new access token
                            .build();
}
```

What could be going on here and why does `addHeader()` not behave the same as `header()`

Comment: ```header()``` renews the existing header of it's ```name``` on each API call, whereas ```addHeader``` adds a new header to the list of headers whilst retaining the previous header that has invalid authorization.

Answer (score 9):

Quoting the documentation :

`header` :

> Sets the header named {@code name} to {@code value}. If this request already has any headers with that name, they are all replaced.

`addHeader` :

> Adds a header with {@code name} and {@code value}. Prefer this method for multiply-valued headers like "Cookie". Note that for some headers including {@code Content-Length} and {@code Content-Encoding}, OkHttp may replace {@code value} with a header derived from the request body.

So `header` will replace if already added, whilst `addHeader` generally will not.

Comment: Ok so there's two different functions and one allows you to have multiple identical header keys? Is there any single use case you can think of where that would be useful?! I just do not understand the purpose of `addHeader` at all

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation .header() will replace whatever value was there with the new value you provide. If you use .addHeader(), the old header remains and you're adding on the new header you pass in.

In other words, using addHeader() will give you two access tokens, the one that doesn't work and the one that works. Using .header() does what you're actually trying to do.